# Using shell script, I need to access a file placed in a location while the script is placed in a different location

Tags: unix, shell-script, path, file-location

I've placed a file in the location

```
/tmp/parent_dir/child_dir/file_1
```

The script is placed in the location

```
/usr/local/bin/file_load/load_data
```

From this location (`/usr/local/bin/file_load/load_data`), how can I access the file (`file_1`) which is placed in another location (`/tmp/parent_dir/child_dir/file_1`) from within the script?

Comment: You do not actually ask any question. Try to state more clearly what exactly is your issue, and give a code sample if it applies.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the shell script to receive the path of the file on the command line? Something like this would help:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
cat $file
```

You can then call the script like this:

```
 /usr/local/bin/file_load/load_data /tmp/parent_dir/child_dir/file_1
```

which will output the file.

Comment: Giridharan: I'm running a script which needs to access files placed in a location other than the location of the corresponding script. To be precise, the files are in one location while the script that access the files are in another location. My question is how to access those files from within the script? When I give the absolute path in the script to refer to the location ('/tmp/parent_dir/child_dir/file_1'), it throws an error saying '/parent_dir/tmp: No such file or directory'

Comment: Can you show us the part of the script where you use the path to the file? The error message doesn't make much sense (parent_dir and tmp have switched positions?).